# z-index the div inside iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm having the following `iframe`:
`<iframe id="uploader" src="/fileuploader"></iframe>`

When it's loaded, there are multiple div elements - I want one of them to be layered on the top of the iframe.

```
<iframe id="uploader" src="/fileuploader">
      [..]
      <div class="modal preview"> <---- I want this to be positioned over iframe
           <div class="modal-body">
                <img src="myimage.jpg" alt="Image">
           </div>
      </div>
      [..]
</iframe>
```

Preview:

### [image: preview]

Looks like this is impossible to achieve since nothing works.

What have I tried:

- Setting z-index on iframe and the div
- Playing with the positions
- Playing with iframe transparency

Question:

How can I z-index an element located inside of the `iframe` over it?

Comment: You can't style the content inside an iframe. Its not a standard.

Comment: The `<iframe>` is supposed to be an element on the parent page. Anything inside the `<iframe>`'s (i.e. `src`) is an entirely different page.

Comment: It is possible to create a modal on a page then embed an `<iframe>` within the modal.

Comment: It is impossible to do this way, the content inside the iframe can not "break out" of it. You will need to place your modal element in the parent document - then you will be able to position it above the iframe, and beyond its edges. If what you want to display inside the modal depends on what happens inside the iframe somehow (user image selection, that you want to show a client-side preview of), then you will have to access that data either from the parent, or have the iframe hand it up to it.